# getOrAwaitValue() method returned IllegalArgumentException when unit testing viewmodel in kotlin

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I am getting the IllegalArgumentException when i run my **PatientViewModelTest** class, i struggled a lot to fix to problem on my own but failed to solve it. Actually i have no idea about why this error is occurring because i'm new in Kotlin as well as Unit Testing. This is my first application in kotlin. Please help me.

Thanks

PatientViewModel.kt

```
import androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelInject
import androidx.lifecycle.*
import com.aitriage.data.Patient
import com.aitriage.data.Staff
import com.aitriage.other.Event
import com.aitriage.other.Resource
import com.aitriage.repository.MainRepository
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class PatientViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val mMainRepository: MainRepository): ViewModel()
{
    val patientList = mMainRepository.getAllPatients()

    private val _insertPatientStatus = MutableLiveData<Event<Resource<Patient>>>()

    val insertPatientStatus : LiveData<Event<Resource<Patient>>> = _insertPatientStatus

    fun insertPatientIntoDB(patient: Patient) = viewModelScope.launch {

        mMainRepository.insertPatient(patient)
    }

    fun insertPatient(age: String, createdAt: String, gender: String,hopitalId:String, patientId: String,race: String, sortKey: String, status: String){
        
        if (age.isEmpty() || createdAt.isEmpty() || gender.isEmpty() || hopitalId.isEmpty() || patientId.isEmpty() || race.isEmpty() || sortKey.isEmpty() || status.isEmpty())
        {
            _insertPatientStatus.postValue(Event(Resource.error(null,"The fields can't be empty")))
            return
        }


        val staff = Staff("Himanshu")
        val patient = Patient(0,staff,age,createdAt, gender,hopitalId,patientId,race,sortKey,status)
        insertPatientIntoDB(patient)
        _insertPatientStatus.postValue(Event(Resource.success(patient)))


    }

 }
```

PatientViewModelTest.kt

```
import android.os.Build
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import com.aitriage.MainCoroutineRule
import com.aitriage.getOrAwaitValue
import com.aitriage.other.Status
import com.google.common.truth.Truth.assertThat
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config

@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class PatientViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    private lateinit var viewModel: PatientViewModel

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        viewModel = Mockito.mock(PatientViewModel::class.java)
    }

    @Test
    fun `insert patient with empty field, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }


    @Test
    fun `insert patient with age is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("", "ds", "ds", "gfdg", "gf", "gf", "fd", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }

    @Test
    fun `insert patient with date is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "", "ds", "gfdg", "gf", "gf", "fd", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }

    @Test
    fun `insert patient with gender is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "sfs", "", "gfdg", "gf", "gf", "fd", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }


    @Test
    fun `insert patient with hopital id is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "sfs", "fs", "", "gf", "gf", "fd", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }

    @Test
    fun `insert patient with patient id is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "sfs", "fs", "gf", "", "gf", "fd", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }


    @Test
    fun `insert patient with race is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "sfs", "fs", "gf", "gf", "", "fd", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }


    @Test
    fun `insert patient with sortkey is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "sfs", "fs", "gf", "gf", "fd", "", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()


        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }

    @Test
    fun `insert patient with status is empty, returns error`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "sfs", "fs", "gf", "gf", "fd", "fd", "")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()

        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.ERROR)
    }

    @Test
    fun `insert patient with valid input, returns success`() {
        viewModel.insertPatient("da", "sfs", "fs", "gf", "gf", "fd", "fd", "gd")

        val value = viewModel.insertPatientStatus.getOrAwaitValue()

        assertThat(value.getContentIfNotHandled()?.status).isEqualTo(Status.SUCCESS)
    }

    @Test
    fun add()
    {
        val actual = 4

        assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(4)
    }
}
```

LiveDataTestUtilClass.kt

```
import androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.NONE)
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
        time: Long = 2,
        timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        afterObserve: () -> Unit = {}
): T {
    var data: T? = null
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
    val observer = object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
            data = o
            latch.countDown()
            this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
        }
    }
    this.observeForever(observer)

    try {
        afterObserve.invoke()

        // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
        if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
            throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
        }

    } finally {
        this.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return data as T
}
```

MainRepository.kt

```
import com.aitriage.data.Help
import com.aitriage.data.input.ForgotPwdInput
import com.aitriage.data.input.LoginInput
import com.aitriage.data.Patient
import com.aitriage.database.HelpDao
import com.aitriage.database.PatientDao
import com.aitriage.network.ApiHelperImpl
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.NonCancellable
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class MainRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val patientDao: PatientDao,
    private val helpDao: HelpDao,
    private val apiHelper: ApiHelperImpl
) {

    suspend fun login(body: LoginInput) = apiHelper.login(body)
    suspend fun forgotPassword(body: ForgotPwdInput) = apiHelper.forgotPassword(body)

    fun getAllPatients() = patientDao.getAllPatients()


    suspend fun insertPatient(patient: Patient)
    {
        patientDao.insertPatient(patient)
    }


    fun getHelp() = helpDao.getHelp(1)

    suspend fun saveHelp(help: Help) = helpDao.saveHelp(help)

    suspend fun getRemoteHelp(authToken: String) = apiHelper.getHelp(authToken)
}
```

This is the actual error i am getting. Please have a look at the screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yx4J.png)

Comment: Your livedata value is null because the test doesn´t wait to the operation result, so the initial value is always.  To solve this,  you needs to use runBlockingTest in your tests, and is probably you need too your mainCoroutineRule, something like: mainCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest { // your test }.  If you need to verify the livedata during a process, for example, isLoadingLiveData with true or false value, then is necessary to pause the coroutine and verify the livedata value using something like mainCoroutineRule.pauseAndResume { // your when and then statements }

Comment: Thanks for replying, i put my test code inside the = runBlockingTest{} but did not succeeded. Can you help me further.

Comment: Actually I'm using getOrAwaitValue() method, so this method actually waits for the livedata.

Comment: Yes, but you are using a coroutine context, so to verify the livedata value you need to use runBlockingTest, if you don´t use, then the livedata value is not updated when the assert is executing, so the value always will be null.  And another thing, you putted this rule @get:Rule  var mainCoroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule() in your ViewModelTest but your are not using it.

Comment: @ManuelMato I have the same problem I did what you said above and it showed me java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: LiveData value was never set. can you help?

Comment: I think your approach is not good... for example, the livedata is using to update the UI in a reactive way, so the UI observe the livedata and, when the an event success, then the UI change.  In your viewmodel you aren´t updating the livedata, the insertPatientIntoDB method is returning a Job... so your ViewModel has a bad approach... the Google recommendation is the previosly that i said, and then you could be to test the viewmodel.

Comment: I remembered that i have some issue but only running the test with gradle: ./gradlew test . The exception it was caused but internally problems between the roboelectric library and mockk library, and is probably the same problem with mockito, so you could update the roboelectric library to 4.4 version and the mockito library.

Comment: I did update them but the same error. my approach followed [Sunflower](https://github.com/android/sunflower) thanks sir I will try to put more time in it